# camera 2 request performance issues

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera

I am using android camera 2 api to receive camera preview as a byte array so I could proceed it later in Unity3d. However I encountered some serious performance problems on my Galaxy Note4. I've got like 200-300ms (then 13, 12 ms and again 200-300) period between capture requests.

From my experiments it looks like a capture request is super slow or it's image loader callback. Do you have an idea how could I improve this? Code below. I'd be grateful for any technical info I might be missing.

```
package com.aind.mfs.cam;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NativeCamera {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private static final String TAG = "CameraJavaMFS";

    public static NativeCamera instance;
    public static String gameObjectTargetName;

    private static final long MICRO_SECOND = 1000;
    private static final long MILLI_SECOND = MICRO_SECOND * 1000;
    private static final long ONE_SECOND = MILLI_SECOND * 1000;

    private String _cameraId;
    private CameraManager _cameraManager;
    private CameraDevice _cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession _cameraCaptureSessions;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder _captureRequestBuilder;
    private ImageReader _imageReader;

    private int _targetWidth;
    private int _targetHeight;
    private int _prevWidth;
    private int _prevHeight;
    private long _sensorFrameDuration = ONE_SECOND / 33;
    private long _exposureTime = ONE_SECOND / 33;
    private HandlerThread _backgroundThread;
    private Handler _backgroundHandler;

    public byte[] bytes;

    public int getPreviewSizeWidth() {
        return _prevWidth;
    }

    public int getPreviewSizeHeight() {
        return _prevHeight;
    }

    public static void init(String gameObjectName) {
        gameObjectTargetName = gameObjectName;
        instance = new NativeCamera();
    }

    public void startCamera(int width, int height) {
        _targetWidth = width;
        _targetHeight = height;

        openCamera();
    }

    public void stopCamera() {
        if (null != _cameraDevice) {
            _cameraDevice.close();
            _cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != _imageReader) {
            _imageReader.close();
            _imageReader = null;
            closeBackgoundThread();
        }
    }

    private void openBackgroundThread() {
        _backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera2 background thread");
        _backgroundThread.start();
        _backgroundHandler = new Handler(_backgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void closeBackgoundThread() {
        _backgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            _backgroundThread.join();
            _backgroundThread = null;
            _backgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        _cameraManager = (CameraManager) App.context().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            _cameraId = _cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            _cameraManager.openCamera(_cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setupCamera() {
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = _cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(_cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            Size[] previewSizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);

            Size optimalSize = getOptimalSize(_targetWidth, _targetHeight, previewSizes);
            _prevWidth = optimalSize.getWidth();
            _prevHeight = optimalSize.getHeight();

            _imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(_prevWidth, _prevHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
            _imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageListener, null);

            assert map != null;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Size getOptimalSize(int width, int height, Size[] sizes) {
        if (_cameraDevice == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CameraDevice is NULL");
            return null;
        }

        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) width / height;

        if (sizes == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera preview sizes is NULL");
            return null;
        }

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int targetWidth = width;

        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.getWidth() / size.getHeight();
            Log.i("Unity", "RES: size=" + size.getWidth() + "/" + size.getHeight() + "/ Aspect Ratio: " + ratio + "target width: " + width + "target height: " + height);

            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.getWidth() - targetWidth) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.getWidth() - targetWidth);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.getWidth() - targetWidth) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.getWidth() - targetWidth);
                }
            }
        }

        Log.i("Unity", "optimal size=" + optimalSize.getWidth() + "/" + optimalSize.getHeight() + "/ Aspect Ratio: " + (double) optimalSize.getWidth() / optimalSize.getHeight());
        return optimalSize;
    }


    private byte[] data0, data1, data2;
    private Image image;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;
    private YuvImage yuvImage;
    private long previusTime;
    private Image.Plane[] planes;

    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            image = null;
            outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {
                image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

                if (image == null) {
                    return;
                }

                ByteBuffer bufferY = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                data0 = new byte[bufferY.remaining()];
                bufferY.get(data0);

                ByteBuffer bufferU = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
                data1 = new byte[bufferU.remaining()];
                bufferU.get(data1);

                ByteBuffer bufferV = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
                data2 = new byte[bufferV.remaining()];
                bufferV.get(data2);

                try {
                    outputStream.write(data0);
                    outputStream.write(data1);
                    outputStream.write(data2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                yuvImage = new YuvImage(outputStream.toByteArray(), ImageFormat.NV21, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
                bytes = yuvImage.getYuvData();
            } finally {
                if (image != null) {
                    image.close();
                }

                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(gameObjectTargetName, "GetBuffer", "");
            }
        }
    };

    private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            NewFrameAvaiableHandler();
        }
    };

    private void NewFrameAvaiableHandler() {
        long startTime = previusTime;
        previusTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG, "Image reader time elapsed: " + (previusTime - startTime));
    }

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            _cameraDevice = camera;
            setupCamera();
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(gameObjectTargetName, "OnCameraReadyHandler", "");
            createCameraPreview();
            openBackgroundThread();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            _cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            _cameraDevice.close();
            _cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            Surface readerSurface = _imageReader.getSurface();

            List surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
            surfaces.add(readerSurface);

            _captureRequestBuilder = _cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            _captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            _captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(readerSurface);

            _cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if (null == _cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }

                    _cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    configurePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void configurePreview() {
        if (null == _cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "UpdatePreview error, CameraDevice is null");
        }

        _captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
        //_captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, _exposureTime);
        //_captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, _sensorFrameDuration);

        try {
            _cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(_captureRequestBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, _backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code of onImageAvailable() introduces too much overhead. Note that it is actually wrong, and will fail on a device that uses different internal pixel arrangement.

Comment: Commenting that whole section did not solve the problem.

Comment: What preview size did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the YUV_420_888 ImageReader with only 1 image buffer:

```
_imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(_prevWidth, _prevHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
```

This means that when onImageAvailable gets called, since the image reader has only 1 ‘Image’ buffer, the camera CaptureRequest workflow will block until you finish copying the YUV data.

The solution is to increase the ImageReader max images. Take into account that the ImageReader ‘max images’ will consume more memory as this is actually allocating more Image buffers, so you should take such factor into consideration.

```
final int MAX_IMAGES = 3;

_imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(_prevWidth, _prevHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, MAX_IMAGES);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this and increasing that number resulted in even less performance.

Comment: Increasing the Max Images shouldn't reduce performance unless the value is too high and the YUV copy takes too long. Take into account that keeping Max Images to only 1 means that you have only 1 Image buffer, and the camera capture request will be halted while the YUV data is being copied. Increasing the Max Images means to add more Image buffers, so while your code is inside onImageAvailable copying the YUV data, the camera capture request can still keep working filling the other Image buffers, so when the YUV copy finishes a new Image is ready to arrive into onImageAvailable.

Comment: Checking further your code, I see you are creating new byte buffers on each OnImageAvailableListener call. This will trigger the garbage collector pretty quickly and reduce the overall app performance, which may explain why you see the delay in interval periods. Instead, you should initialize and reuse your byte arrays instead of creating them continuously, which definitely will trigger a GC call and halt your code.